# How to achieve an atomic reading for combined data in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

In the following code, `LocalCache` stands for a `Map<String, float[]>` that could consume up to serveral GB memory. The idea is that each `String` in `keys` has a 256 sized `float[]` data.

```
public class LocalCache {
   int size;
   List<String> keys;
   float[] data;
   
   public void synchronized add(String oneKey, float[] oneData) {
       for (int i = 0; i<oneData.length; i++) {
          this.data[i+256*size] = oneData[i];
       }
       keys.add(oneKey);
       size++;
   }
   
}

foo() {
   localCache.getData();
   localCache.getKeys();
   localCache.getSize();
}
```

The question is when a function like `foo`, uses `data` and `keys` and `size`, how to make sure that they are identical?

Comment: You need a `synchronized` block around all the reading operations or use a `ReadLock` that `LocalCache` needs to expose. But this design is really flawed, why not use a `ConcurrentMap<String, List<Float>>`?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is just:

```java
foo() {
  synchronized(localCache) {
    localCache.getData();
    localCache.getKeys();
    localCache.getSize();
  }
}
```

But it might have poor performance. If the calls to the `add` method are rare enough with regards to the calls to the getters, you can use a ReadWriteLock. The add method would lock for writing (exclusive lock), while the foo method would lock for reading (shared lock with other readers).

If you need higher throughput (the add method is called often), I would create an intermediate data structure:

```java
class Data {
  String key;
  float[] oneData;
}

class LocalCache {
  final Queue<Data> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

  public void add(String key, float[] data) { // no need to synchronize
    queue.add(new Data(key, data));
  }
}

foo() {
   List<Data> currentData = new ArrayList<>(localCache.getQueue());
   // will not copy your several GB of data, only pointers to the Data objects.
   // Will get the entire content of the queue at some point in time,
   // the result of the latest add operations may be missing.
}
```

Also, if you only need a `Map<String, float[]>` that support concurrent access, as f1sh pointed out, just use ConcurrentHashMap. It is very efficient.